Http-only cookie in response header from backend, but not being stored in client browser
I have a fullstack app made up of a React frontend and a FastAPI (python) backend, both of which are currently being served locally on 127.0.0.1 (localhost).
BACKEND:
Here is the code for my backend server, with CORSMiddleware and SessionMiddleware configured:
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, status, Request
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

app = FastAPI()

# generated via cmd: 'openssl rand -hex 32'
SECRET_KEY = "XXX"

origins = [
    "http://localhost",
    "https://localhost",
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "https://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1",
    "https://127.0.0.1",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    "https://127.0.0.1:3000",
]

# https://www.starlette.io/middleware/#corsmiddleware
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

# https://www.starlette.io/middleware/#sessionmiddleware
app.add_middleware(
    SessionMiddleware,
    secret_key=SECRET_KEY,
    https_only=True,
    max_age=3600,  # 3600s = 1hr, the life of spotify access token
    same_site="none",
)

CLIENT_ID = "YYYY"
CLIENT_SECRET = "ZZZ"
OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/"
SCOPE = "playlist-read-private playlist-read-collaborative user-read-private user-read-email"

# Docs: https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.24.0/#module-spotipy.oauth2
sp_oauth = SpotifyOAuth(client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, redirect_uri=OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI, scope=SCOPE)

@app.post("/spotify-auth", tags=["auth"])
def exchange_token(code: str, request: Request):
    # Exchanges token, with check_cache=False to ensure new users can be registered
    token_info = sp_oauth.get_access_token(code=code, check_cache=False)
    print(token_info)
    # https://www.starlette.io/middleware/#sessionmiddleware
    request.session["access_token"] = token_info["access_token"]
    request.session["refresh_token"] = token_info["refresh_token"]
    return {"tokenSaved": True}

In other endpoints, i.e. /user, when I try to access request.session.get("access_token"), I get absolutely nothing back.
FRONTEND:
here is the axios POST request from my frontend (react/typescript) that will hit the /spotify-auth endpoint on my backend:
const exchangeSpotifyAuthToken = async (
    code: string,
): Promise<AccessTokenReponse> => {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    searchParams.append("code", code);
    const response = await axios.post(
        `${API_URL_BASE}/spotify-auth?` + searchParams.toString(),
        { withCredentials: true },
    );
    return response.data;
};

But as I said, my attempts to use the access_token in other routes, which should be accessible via request.session.get("access_token") all fail. Each of my axios requests also include this { withCredentials: true } config, so that shouldn't be the problem.
THINGS I'VE TRIED:
I've seen a lot of CORS related posts regarding this issue, and I think I have implemented the requirements as follows:

CORSMiddleware allowed origins on backend configured to receive requests from my frontend (127.0.0.1:3000)
allow_credentials=True on backend
Frontend and backend located at same domain: 127.0.0.1
requests from frontend configured with withCredentials: true

BROWSER TOOLS:
I also checked the browser tools Network tab and saw that my session was being correctly recorded following my POST request to login/authenticate:

But any followup requests to my backend do not contain this session cookie, so they promptly fail my authentication check:

Shouldn't my session cookie show up in those request headers so that my backend can retrieve them? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

No modern browser will accept attempts by an insecure Web origin like https://127.0.0.1:8000 to create a cookie marked Secure; browsers silently rejects such attempts. That's why, despite the presence of a Set-Cookie header, the cookie in question doesn't get created in the browser.

You could check if the browser actually stored the cookie. It's under the Storage tab of dev tools, but because of the different domains, you may have to "open" localhost:8000 first.

@jub0bs localhost often has special rules, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#secure

It also matters how complicated your actual page is, like setting cookies from inside an <iframe> can be blocked depending on browser and/or its settings (you can succeed with Firefox, but should you ever come across a Safari user, it will just break).

you can see in the request header screenshot that httponly and secure are set, so the browser should accept the cookie... but when I check 'Cookies' in the dev tools storage tab, there is none. So it clearly isn't being accepted.
What am I doing wrong? I am clearly following all of the documentation of FastAPI, MDN CORS, etc...

@tevemadar Thanks; I didn't know that. Very interesting. I read all cookie-related RFCs, but I don't remember reading about that exception in them. It seems to be a deviation from the RFCs that browsers chose to implement. According to my tests, 127.0.0.1 also works. I wonder whether all loopback IPs work...

@tevemadar For what it's worth, I implemented similar exceptions for localhost and loopback IPs in my CORS middleware library for Go.

@tprebenda if you're not completely against Chrome, you could try the thing in it. Then it has a separate view chrome://settings/content/all where you could see if there's a cookie for localhost:8000  or not (though in this view you can't see its content just if it exists).

In addition to the link provided above, you might find this answer and this answer helpful as well.

I must not have been keeping good track of which possible solution I was trying... I think I may have mix and mashed them, which resulted in the cookies not being stored.
Ultimately I had domain=".localhost" in my SessionMiddleware, like so:
app.add_middleware(
    SessionMiddleware,
    secret_key=SECRET_KEY,
    https_only=True,
    max_age=3600,  # 3600s = 1hr, the life of spotify access token
    same_site="none",
    domain=".localhost"   # THIS WAS WHAT WAS KILLING ME
)

This was a suggestion I had seen online, but that must have been when I was serving my frontend on localhost and not 127.0.0.1.
Now that both my backend and frontend are being served on 127.0.0.1, I recognized this faulty domain specification and removed it. The backend session middleware now correctly sends cookies to the default domain (that of the backend, 127.0.0.1) and my cookies are being correctly stored!!
Still have to confirm that I can actually use the session cookies as intended in my other API endpoints, but I'll just enjoy the moment and worry about that tomorrow :)
Thanks for the comments/suggestions!
